# Shared local memory in PIX debugger

Tags: hlsl, directx-12

I'm trying to debug a compute shader. I'd like to step through the shader and inspect the value of groupshared memory:

```
groupshared float a[LENGTH];
```

But the value is always `<unavailable>`.

Is there anyway to get around this?

I try to copy to a local

```
float aa[8];
for (uint z = 0; z < LENGTH; z++) aa[z] = a[z];
```

but they you have to used it somehow or it will disappear from autos and be `<not live>` in watches. What's a good way to keep the variable alive for debugging?